# Dynamic Spring Security update

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I faced issue trying to get my roles updated from DB. Is it possible to programmatically add configuration to spring security. e.g.

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
          .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN");
```

Can i add a new configuration say `.antMatchers("/user-service/**").hasRole("USER_DRIVER");` programmatically?

I tried adding a scheduled job using spring boot to refresh the configuration. However, they are not accepted.

Help appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue?